# Random Loot list for Magic Items

Tags: dnd-4e, treasure

Does anyone have some sort of random Loot list for magic and non-magic items? My group prefers the random approach when it comes to magic items. I am using Sly Flourish´s [random loot table](http://slyflourish.com/random_loot_tables.html) for now, but want to check out alternatives if available.

Answer (score 9):

**The Rules Compendium has what you're looking for.**

The Rules Compendium, p 295, has random loot tables in lieu of treasure parcels. [This answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/29916/760) discusses the fundamental mechanics, It also looks like someone has made an [excel spreadsheet](http://www.enworld.org/forum/showthread.php?301397-Random-Treasure-Parcel-Generator-%28D-amp-D-Rules-Compendium%29) to do the rolling for you.